# Using Extended Euclidean Algorithm to create RSA private key

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption, rsa, modular-arithmetic

This is for an assignment I'm doing through school. I am having trouble generating a private key. My main problem is understanding the relation of my equations to each other. To set everything up, we have:

```
p = 61
q = 53
n = p * q (which equals 3233)
```

From here we have the totient of n (`phi(n)`) which equals 3120, now we can choose prime e; where 1 < e < 3120

```
e = 17
```

Okay easy enough.

For my assignment we've been made aware that `d = 2753`, however I still need to be able to arbitrarily generate this value.

Now here is where I am having trouble. I've been perusing wikipedia to understand and somewhere something isn't connecting. I know that I need to find the [modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of `e (mod phi(n))` which will be `d`, our private exponent.

Reading though wikipedia tells us to find the mmi we need to use the [Extended Euclidian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Iterative_method_2). I've implemented the algorithm in python as follows:

```
def egcd(a, b):
    x, lastX = 0, 1
    y, lastY = 1, 0
    while (b != 0):
        q = a // b
        a, b = b, a % b
        x, lastX = lastX - q * x, x
        y, lastY = lastY - q * y, y
    return (lastX, lastY)
```

This is where I am lost. To my understanding now, the equation `ax + bx = gcd(a, b) = 1` is the same `e*x + phi(n)*y = gcd(e, phi(n)) = 1`.
So we call `egcd(e, phi(n))`, and now I get `[-367, 2]` for my x and y.

From here I honestly don't know where to go. I've read [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67171/calculating-the-modular-multiplicative-inverse-without-all-those-strange-looking) and I see that there are some substitutions that happen, but I don't understand how those number relate to the answer that I got or the values I have started out with. Can someone explain to me pragmatically what I need to do from here? (When I say pragmatically, I mean without actual code. Pseudo code is fine, but if I get actual code I won't be able to learn without plagiarism on my assignment which is a big no-no).

As always, any help is genuinely appreciated. Thanks everyone!

(And yes, I have seen these:[RSA: Private key calculation with Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422633/rsa-private-key-calculation-with-extended-euclidean-algorithm?rq=1) and [In RSA encryption, how do I find d, given p, q, e and c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310871/in-rsa-encryption-how-do-i-find-d-given-p-q-e-and-c))

Comment: I have also already read this too: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/calculating-rsa-private-exponent-when-given-public-exponent-and-the-modulus-fact

Comment: -367 and 2753 are the same number (mod 3120).

Comment: Omg. You've gott'a be kidding me. I've been messing around with literally dozens of different combinations for hours without success. I don't know I didn't think of that one, thanks a million!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that in most programming languages `%` is not the modulo function but the **remainder** function. It's not much of a difference, but it can be fun if you end up with a negative integer instead of a positive one.

Comment: Oh really? That is something that definitely helps. In trying a couple other examples I was getting somewhat inconsistent results and I didn't know why (I'm still looking through my code to see if I have goofed up somewhere, which is more than somewhat likely.). For these intents and purposes, is there a more-correct way to find the mod of a number in python3 than using the % operator?

Comment: Actually based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907565/c-python-different-behaviour-of-the-modulo-operation it looks like the Modulo function should be behaving the way it's supposed to in this situation, right?

Comment: Double actually, I may have to do some tinkering. This question has even more information regarding the mod operator's functionality: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775/modulus-operation-with-negatives-values-weird-thing

Answer (score 8):

The implementation of the Extended Euclidean algorithm you have is not complete, since it is generating a negative number for the private key. Use this code instead:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

For your example the private key, d, is 2753.

```
p=61
q=53
n = 3233
phi(n)=3120
e=17
d=modinv(17,3120)=2753
```

Try it out:

```
message m m=65


encryption: m^e mod n = c    (65**17) % 3120 =  65
decryption: c^d mod n = m      (65**2753) % 3120 =   65
```

Its all explained here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20141209083336/http://southernpacificreview.com/2014/01/06/rsa-key-generation-example/

Answer (score 3):

```
def egcd(a,b):   
    s1, s2 = 1, 0   
    t1, t2 = 0, 1   
    while b!=0:   
        q = a//b    
        r = a%b   
        a, b = b, r     
        s = s1-q*s2    
        s1, s2 = s2, s      
        t = t1-q*t2    
        t1, t2 = t2, t    
    return (s1, t1)
```

> try comparing above.
>
> i will tell you where was your mistake:
>
> a, b = b, a % b
>
> a has the value of b now 
>   (b=a%b)==(b=b%b)
>   and similar reason for proceeding two lines